# Why couldn't "org.antlr.v4.runetime.misc.TestRig" not be found or load?

Tags: java, antlr4

So, here's my problem. I've got my ANTLR4 code successfully compiled, without errors and now I want to test it out. The ANTLR4 Documentation tells me, to test my applications, I shall do this:

```
java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig
```

I've tried this and got following error:

> Error: Main Class org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig couldn't be found or load.

I've checked if my CLASSPATH wasn't set, but everything was correctly set as it should be. I also tried moving the file directly to my test folder and opened CMD there and tried it again, I occur the same error. Searching in the Internet didn't help, as no one seemed to have occurred this error with ANTLR4 before.

Specs:

Java 1.7.0.55

ANTLR 4.4

Comment: Can you add the complete stacktrace please.

Comment: @Jens There's no stacktrace. It just showed that the main class couldn't be found or load. If it's somehow possible to dump it, then please tell me and I do.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: In the CLASSPATH, the jar file name must match the downloaded jar file
e.g. if you have downloaded the "antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar" the CLASSPATH should be:
.;C:\Javalib\antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%
where "C:\Javalib" is the path where you installed antlr-4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with your classpath, contrary to your belief everything is okay.

When I download the ANTLR 4 JAR and run `TestRig`:

```
wget http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.4-complete.jar
...
java -cp antlr-4.4-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig
```

I see the following on my console:

```
java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig GrammarName startRuleName
  [-tokens] [-tree] [-gui] [-ps file.ps] [-encoding encodingname]
  [-trace] [-diagnostics] [-SLL]
  [input-filename(s)]
Use startRuleName='tokens' if GrammarName is a lexer grammar.
Omitting input-filename makes rig read from stdin.
```

Comment: I try to re-install ANTLR4. Maybe I really did something wrong in there.

Comment: Still not working. Re-installed everything, incl. Java, ANTLR4, etc. Still I get a class not found error.

Comment: Well, I just showed you there is nothing wrong with `antlr-4.4-complete.jar`. If you download version 4.4 and do exactly as I do, you'll see "it" works. Without access to your machine, I cannot help. It is probably something relates to your classpath, or the machine needing a restart or whatever. Good luck.

Comment: Look at comment from where @BartKiers mentioned for downloading 4.4 complete jar. It worked for me in case of 4.7 version download.